# When do you need to create your dynamic array instead of using Python's List class?

Tags: python, arrays, list, data-structures, dynamic-arrays

The Python List class has all the methods we need for a dynamic array. Is there any advantage to creating a custom dynamic array as in this example? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementation-of-dynamic-array-in-python/

Comment: What kind of advantages would you care about if they did exist?

Comment: The example is poorly written, with some real bugs and some "design bugs", and appears to have no capabilites that `list` doesn't have. It doesn't claim there's any benefit to doing this, just that it can be done. Presumably the point is to learn, by practice and example, how to use `ctypes` (and methods like `__len__` and `__getitem__`). Due to the bugs and lack of detailed explanations, I don't recommend using that article to learn those things.

Comment: Python `list`s _are_ dynamic arrays. The only advantage of implementing this is for education.

Comment: Michale and Dan, thank you! Yeah, I thought so too. I just wasn't sure.